# Vector design software recommendation for logo design

Tags: vector, software-recommendation

What programs under $100 are good for vector design?  I can't use subscriptions and illustrator is just way too expensive.  I have been looking at Affinity Designer and think it is the best option for what I want to do: Logo Design.  Also:  are drawing tablets good for logo design?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your style. I've been in the market for a good vector software for a while. Personally I find that neither [Affinity Designer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_Designer) nor [Inkscape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape) do not work well for me. Inkscape is just net negative in productivity for me and Affinity Designer is too one-sided and missing things I need for precision work.

I never really liked [CorelDraw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CorelDRAW) for some reason, but it's got better as of late, and I am thinking of doing a full reevaluation on CorelDraw. For a long time I've been looking at [Xara Designer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xara_Photo_%26_Graphic_Designer), which is one feature short of me switching over. Both of these are out of your range tough.

Sketch is actually OK, for a subset of my work. But the Mac-only feature set is not my cup of tea.

Comment: I actually think that about Ilustrator. Corel has some features I am used to work that can not find on Ilustrator.

Comment: @Rafael Its not missing features its about feel of features. I literally choose illustrator because the grid snap feels better. I dont need features as such all i need is a API that allows me to make the features. Which is horrendous in Illustrator and nonexistent in Xara-

Comment: Multipage. (The artboards in ilustrator, in my opinion are a mess n_n) and the exactitude in the snaping actually. I have not tried lately but I found the snap in Ilustrator quite inacurate. But that would be a long discussion n_n. But yeap, probably it is amatter of "feel".

Comment: @Rafael grid snap can not be inaccurate! But adobe can not cannibalize itself.

Comment: Not on grid, on objects. (Shhhh. Some will come and scold at us for this discusion on the comment area) n_n

Comment: @Rafael We can move to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49060/discussion-between-rafael-and-joojaa).

Answer (score 1):

For your computer, you can use Inkscape for free. For your touch screen device (iPhone, iPad, etc.), you can use Assembly (which is mostly free, but offers cheap in-app purchases).

Answer (score 1):

The free option is [Inkscape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape).

Affinity Designer is an interesting option. Affinity Photo has already a good reputation.

Another option is CorelDRAW. The last version is around USD$500.

There is a legacy option, [CorelDRAW Graphics Suite X5](http://www.coreldraw.com/la/product/coreldraw-legacy/), which is quite good, but I am not sure if that version has some kind of expiration date when installed, and I am not sure if it can be installed in English.

And regarding if a tablet is good for logo design. I guess it depends on the tablet, but I would say you need a mouse for logo design.

Answer (score 0):

The [CorelDraw Home & Student Suite](http://www.coreldraw.com/en/product/home-student/?topNav=en) is $99 but it only runs on Windows. I think that your best bet is Affinity Designer though.
Drawing tablets are good for freehand drawing, if you're going for a handdrawn look in your logo then yes, but I'd stick to a mouse, personally.