# Getting vector graphics software that works on windows 7 in 2021

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corel-draw

I need a vector graphics software that works on Windows 7. I'm a strong opponent to programmed obsolescence, and I have strong objections against monthly subscription plans to use a piece of software you will never own. My computer is old but still working fine, and I see no reasons for buying a new machine with Windows 10.

I wanted to know if anybody knew of a place where I could get older copies of CorelDraw of Adobe Illustrator. I would obviously prefer legal answers.

Thanks.

Comment: Try Inkscape (free and Open Source). It's updated regularly. Recent version works on Windows 7 and later. It's main purpose is for creating SVG graphics for the web.

Comment: Similar question [Vector design software recommendation for logo design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80715/vector-design-software-recommendation-for-logo-design)

Comment: It's possible to find (legal) older Adobe software by searching Amazon.